# How push notification works on every browsers when the website is closed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, safari, push

I want to show the latest news of website in a notification on every browser when the website is opened or closed.

May I know how to implement the process? Which push api I need to use ? What is the procedure ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to add push notifications to your site, you'll need to understand which technology/API is used for communicating between the client and server even the browser is closed. The Service Worker API allows this and you'll need to add a service worker to your site for push notifications to work.

> Service workers essentially act as proxy servers that sit between web applications, the browser, and the network (when available). They are intended, among other things, to enable the creation of effective offline experiences, intercept network requests and take appropriate action based on whether the network is available, and update assets residing on the server. They will also allow access to push notifications and background sync APIs.

Source: [MDN - Service Worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)

**NOTE:** In order for a Service Worker to work, your website needs to be secure and run on `https://` For local development, this is not a requirement.

Once you have the Service Worker running, you'll need to register the user for accepting push notification. This allows the server to send messages to the client. Have a look at [Push Notifications: What are they and how do I send them?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATYhOlK11QM) to gain a better understanding of this process.

As this topic is quite brought and there are a lot of moving parts that you need to understand, I'd suggest to get familiar with Service Workers and Push Notifications through tutorials and articles. Here are a few free resources that I found helpful.

[Service Workers - an Introduction](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers)
[Offline Web applications](https://udacity.com/course/offline-web-applications--ud899)
[Service Workers: Push Notifications](https://dbwriteups.wordpress.com/2015/11/16/service-workers-part-5-push-notifications)
[Set Up a JavaScript Firebase Cloud Messaging Client App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)